# What exactly is a android skin

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, skin

I am new at this forum, and this is my first question.
I have no idea what is a android skin
I have searched for something but I don't understand what exactly is..

In the android `AVD`, there is an option to set the android skin to

> HVGA, QVGA, WSVGA, etc.

I want to open the android avd emulator to test a game made in `unity3d`, and I want to try with all android devices, and I just met with this, and I have no idea what I have to do.

Comment: It's a "cover" for your emulator. Just to "dress" it to look like a real device. I never used one, never felt the need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Simple Google Search about those terms would have got you the answer.

They are Screen Resolutions. Different devices come in Different Screen Sizes and Resolutions. 
VGA - Video Graphics Array
HVGA - Half VGA 
QVGA - Quarter VGA
WSVGA:Wide Super VGA

For more information : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution

Also for AVD Info : https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html